# Convert.ToString not handling null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've read that Convert.ToString should handle null, but it doesn't work when it's passed a null object in my code

In this case the object "Name" is null.

```
var name = Convert.ToString(Name.LastName);
```

I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is not caused by `Convert.ToString()`.

The exception is in your code because you are trying to get the value of `LastName` from a null reference. This causes the runtime exception.

To fix it, you'll need to check that `Name` is not null before you try to access `LastName`.

```
var name = Name != null ? Convert.ToString(Name.LastName) : null;
```

Comment: thanks....for my case though, I used var name = Name != null ? Convert.ToString(Name.LastName) : "";

Comment: This answer is wrong.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355736/why-does-convert-tostringnull-return-a-different-value-if-you-cast-null) for the reason: because even when Name is not null, if Lastname is null, the result will be null.

Comment: @shipr That's irrelevant to the question being asked above. My answer addressed the original question - what was causing the runtime NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 10):

That has nothing to do with `Convert.ToString`. You're trying to access `LastName` via a null reference. That's a runtime exception.

Both `Name` and `LastName` can be null here. `Convert.ToString` will never be called in the code above if `Name` is null.

Comment: What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe something like string name = Name == null ? null : Convert.ToString(Name.LastName);

Comment: This answer is wrong; Name cannot be null or the error will appear, but if Lastname is null, so will the result be null.

Comment: @shipr please read the question again. It explicitly states that `Name` is null.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, when C# evaluates Name.LastName it will crash. This is because you are really evaluating Null.LastName, which doesn't make sense. Conver.ToString(Null), will work.

Answer (score 2):

When `Name` is null, you can't access a .LastName of a `null`.

```
var name = Convert.ToString((Name != null) ? Name.LastName : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, your code says to do the following:

1. Find the object `Name` in memory.
2. Find the `LastName` field on the object `Name`
3. Pass that `Name.LastName` field to the `Convert.ToString` method
4. Assign the result to `name`

Your code fails on step 2.  Since `Name` is null, there is no `Name.LastName` field available, so you never make it to step 3.  Therefore, it doesn't matter whether or not `Convert.ToString` correctly handles a null parameter, since the `NullReferenceException` was thrown before you even called `Convert.ToString`.